# How to pass database UNIQUE constraint violation information to web form view layer?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Java RESTful web service (Jersey) to do a web form submission. The user submits a web form and the information is stored in MySQL database after submission. I'm using Spring JDBC for DB operations. The web form has three fields: id, name, and DOB. The id must be unique in the DB. So if the user submits a duplicate existing id field, the form should stay and alert: "ID must be unique". However, I don't know how to pass the DB unique constraint exception to the view layer in my code. My code looks like the following:

```
public class CustomerJDBCTemplate implements CustomerDAO {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;


    public void create(int id, String name, Date dob) {
        String sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO Person (id, name, dob) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplateObject.update(sqlStmt, new Integer(id), name, dob);
        System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name);
    }

        // ......
}
```

The controller class in my presentation layer is:

```
@Path("/customer")
public class CustomerService {

    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context HttpServletRequest request;
    @Context HttpServletResponse response;

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    CustomerJDBCTemplate dbController = (CustomerJDBCTemplate) context.getBean("customerJDBCTemplate");


    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Path("created")
    public Response createCustomer(@FormParam("id") int id,
            @FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("dob") Date dob)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        URI uri = URI.create(uriInfo.getPath());
        Response r;


        try {
            dbController.create(id, name, dob); //This may throw exception.

                    request.setAttribute("name", name);
            request.setAttribute("dob", dob);
            request.setAttribute("id", Integer.valueOf(id));
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/confirm.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            String errMsg = ex.getMessage();
            System.out.println(errMsg);
        //To do: what should I put here to pass the "id already exists" information to the users?
        }

        r = Response.created(uri).build();
        return r;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable displayForm() {
        return new Viewable("/form.html");
    }
}
```

In the above code, the following line may throw an exception if the enter ID already exists in the DB:

```
dbController.create(id, name, dob); //This may throw exception.
```

So how do I catch the DB UNIQUE constraint exception and present this error information to the web form? My web form is `form.html` which will go to `confirm.jsp` if submitted info is correct. But if the entered id is existing, I want the web form to stay at the current page and prompt user the error info. So what should I write to propagate the DB error to the view layer?

**Update**

I've added the following line to catch the exception due to DB error:

```
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
```

But this will only direct to an Internal Server Error page after the user clicks "Submit" button. So how can I make the web form stay there and prompt user "ID already exists" message when the user enters an existing ID?

Comment: this `RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/confirm.jsp");            dispatcher.forward(request, response);` is kind of weird inside a restful service! I think you read this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: @fGo: I used this dispatcher to map `confirm.jsp` to the resource `/myapp/rest/customer/created` if the form submission is complete and successful. That's why there is an annotation `@Path("created")` used before the method `public Response createCustomer`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've typically seen this done is to use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` [column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for the id so you're guaranteed a unique id by the database.  In other words, you don't allow the user to enter the id, you manage the id under the covers for the user.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I just use id as an example. So in case of some other fields which impose a UNIQUE constraint, I want to pass the error info to the view layer to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException` is a sub class of `DataAccessException`. This will be thrown in case of primary key unique violations.

You can choose to catch this Exception in your controller and then do appropriate action.

```
try {
    dbController.create(id, name, dob); //This may throw exception.
}
catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e)
{
    // your logic for showing error message
}
catch(DataAccessException e)
{
    // general logic to handle exception
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how do I pass the error message so that the web form will stay there and show the error message? I basically want to use Jersey framework instead of Spring MVC to achieve this when DB error is caught.

Comment: @tona - It will depend on how you have configured your web pages to use Jersey. In case you are using Ajax, then pass a standard error message back to the page and update the corresponding UI. In case of success message, you can move to a different view. If you are not using Ajax, then please provide more details on how you do the submit and move to different pages

Comment: I'm using Jersey REST API. So if I want to use Ajax, how should I pass the error message back to client browser in case there is an error like the DB violation exception? The client side is a simple web form. Thanks.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it. You can return an error http response code like 400/409 for this case with some detailed message and then handle it in the client browser. Or alternatively you can return 200 success response, but modify the response text to indicate to the client browser that this is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add another parameter as you do with `name`, `dob` and `id`. Something like this:

```
public Response createCustomer(@FormParam("id") int id,
        @FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("dob") Date dob)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    URI uri = URI.create(uriInfo.getPath());
    Response r;

    String error = null;
    try {
        dbController.create(id, name, dob); //This may throw exception.

    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        String errMsg = ex.getMessage();
        System.out.println(errMsg);
        error = "ID already exists";
    }

    request.setAttribute("name", name);
    request.setAttribute("dob", dob);
    request.setAttribute("id", Integer.valueOf(id));
    request.setAttribute("error", error);//indicates IF there was an error or not
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/confirm.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    r = Response.created(uri).build();
    return r;
}
```