# How do I show error information in web form?

Tags: java, forms

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17046991/1649466). But since I haven't solved that question yet, I want to restate my problem a bit. I'm using Java Jersey REST API as my backend web service. The client side is a simple web form HTML page. Basically what I want is: If the user submits a web form and there are some errors caused by database unique constraint violation, I want the user to see an error message showing along with the id field in the form such as "ID already exists!". The web form is a simple form.html:

```
<form action="/myapp/rest/customer/created" method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Customer name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer ID:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer DOB:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="dob"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If there is an error occurred, how to pass the error information from Jersey API to the client-side? My server-side POST call associated with this form submission is as follows:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("created")
public Response createCustomer(@FormParam("id") int id,
        @FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("dob") Date dob)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    URI uri = URI.create(uriInfo.getPath());
    Response r;
    r = Response.created(uri).build();

    try {
        dbController.create(id, name, dob); //This may throw exception.

    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {

        //To do: How to pass the error message to the client-side UI via e.g., Ajax?

    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: What you can validate on the client-side (JS/jQuery) you should do on the client-side. If you want to make server-side validations you can implement it either by using AJAX or by submitting the form.

Comment: I need to do server-side validation since the error comes from DB validation. But how to pass the DB violation to client-side via AJAX? The user should still see the same page but with the error information.

Comment: The server doesn't "pass things to the client side via AJAX", the client side sends a request to the server to validate things via AJAX and displays the response on the client-side without a page refresh. Read about AJAX to find out more.

Comment: Thanks alfasin. Do you mean I can use for example jQuery ajax call to send the request to the server for data validation? If so, the server sends back the response with the error information if there is an error, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

First of all add this somewhere in your code. It will display the error message:

```
<span id="errorDiv" name="errorDiv" class="errorDiv" ></span>
```

Next, modify your form declaration as:

```
<form action="/myapp/rest/customer/created" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
```

Before submitting the form it will call checkForm() function. if the function returns true then it will post the form. if not then it will prevent form from submission and display error message.

Assuming that you are submitting the form contents by using jQuery/AJAX calls. You can return a String(default value = 'success') from the server. In case there is an error change the specific string and return it and check the value client-side.

responseTxt is the value returned.

```
function checkForm(){
  //get values from form
  var name= $("#name").val();               
  var id= $("#id").val();
  var dob= $("#dob").val();

  $.post('DESTINATION',{name:name,id:id,dob:dob},function(responseTxt) {
  //MAKE YOUR CHECK HERE. JUST AN EXAMPLE
  if (responseTxt.substring(0,4)=='succ'){
  //redirect to destination
    return true;

  }else{

  //display error in errorDiv span

  $('#errorDiv').html('<font color=red>Wrong username or password.</font>');

  //prevents form to be submitted
  return false;
  }

  });
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It still doesn't help. It will go to a page showing "Internal Server Error" page if the submission fails.